# Is it possible to swap 2 cells in a UICollectionView that is using UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

Say I have a UICollectionView using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and the following format:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I touch cell 9 and drag it over cell 6, moving cell 9 to where cell 6 is and cell 6 to where cell 9 was:

```
1 2 3
4 5 9
7 8 6
```

Is there any way to easily move and animate cell 6 to where cell 9 is as well as move and animate cell 9 to where cell 6 is? Or do I have to subclass UICollectionViewLayout? If I have to subclass UICollectionViewLayout, how would this be done? I've tried explicitly setting the centers of the cells in

`-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

but to no success.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After much head banging, the solution I found is to use `moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath` inside of `performBatchUpdates:completion`. According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/performBatchUpdates:completion:) for `performBatchUpdates:completion`:

> You can use this method in cases where you want to insert, delete, reload or move cells around the collection view in one single animated operation, as opposed to in several separate animations. Use the blocked passed in the updates parameter to specify all of the operations you want to perform.

So, what I essentially did was

```
[self performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self moveItemAtIndexPath:fromIp toIndexPath:toIp];
    [self moveItemAtIndexPath:toIp toIndexPath:fromIp];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // update data source here
    // e.g [dataSource exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIp.row withObjectAtIndex:toIp.row];
}];
```

Comment: Can you provide some code or tutorial where this specific issue has been explained. how did you solve this issue.?

Comment: Can you provide any clue to this problem in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803120/how-to-rotate-an-image-on-touch-and-drag-image-over-another-image/25803505?noredirect=1#comment40364549_25803505

Comment: Hi Zac24. I'm not aware of any sample code for this specific issue. Sorry.

Comment: Also, it looks like the question you linked to was answered. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you are willing to help then I can put my code/project to show what I have tried till now.

Comment: Hey Zac24. I won't be able to look at the code without the xCode project.

Comment: Oh I sent you the wrong link. check this https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mlbdvesx22j0u5/Dress%20Your%20Way.zip?dl=0

Comment: I looked over the code. I can't build it so I am unable to test this: 

1. delete the 2 lines of code in ClosetViewController on lines 115 and 116. 
2. insert this line of code: [strongSelf.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:self.startIndex toIndexPath:strongSelf.moveToIndexPath];

Comment: I have tried this but no luck and as of now my cells are not even draggable, I can't Drag them also, what's the issue you are facing in building the project?

Comment: It is missing some assets that are located in your Downloads folder

Comment: I have tried this along with LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout but the issue is there is an annoying cross fade when you move items. As you move, the previous cell fades and is still visible when the item is moved to another location.

Comment: @DeepakSharma: Have you tried using just UICollectionViewFlowLayout instead of LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-ordering the items directly using moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: ?

-make sure you actually re-order the underlying model collection so that the changes stick when you do a full reload next time.

Comment: Yes, I've tried doing that. But since I'm using UICollectionViewFlowLayout, the animation doesn't work properly since it tries to update the cells between the source and destination index paths.

Answer (score 0):

Swift code:

```
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.moveItem(at: selectedIndexPath, to: targetIndexPath)
            self.collectionView.moveItem(at: targetIndexPath, to: selectedIndexPath)
        }, completion: nil)
```