# How to make a cell of UICollectionView ignore position change when the other cells are reordered ？

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How to make a cell of `UICollectionView` ignore position change when the other cells are reordered ？

For example

**Inital cells**

> ＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

Move cell4 to cell1, it will be

> ＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝cell4 cell1 cell2 cell3＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

Now, I want to ***ignore cell3 position change***, it should be

> ＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝cell4 cell1 cell3 cell2＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

I am using this API for reordering:

```
- (void)moveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I understand, you want to swap the position of two cells. It is possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886617/is-it-possible-to-swap-2-cells-in-a-uicollectionview-that-is-using-uicollectionv).

Also, you can [refer](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout).

Comment: there are something different between I want to do and swap two cells. I want to only one cell never change position

Comment: **[self moveItemAtIndexPath:fromIp toIndexPath:toIp];**---> cell4 to cell1
**[self moveItemAtIndexPath:toIp+2 toIndexPath:toIp+3];**---> cell2 to cell3
    **[self moveItemAtIndexPath:toIp+3 toIndexPath:toIp+2];**--->cell3 to cell2.    we thought you required how to do these multiple position switching. I guess this part is logical, like how where and which position you want to move.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)theCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)theSectionIndex {
    return DisplayCollOrderAlbumArrImages.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    LivresCollectionOrderVCCell *playingCardCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [playingCardCell.aImageView setImageWithURL:[DisplayCollOrderAlbumArrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noimgavailable.png"]];

    return playingCardCell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath willMoveToIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSString *imagename = DisplayCollOrderAlbumArrImages[fromIndexPath.item];

    [DisplayCollOrderAlbumArrImages removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.item];
    [DisplayCollOrderAlbumArrImages insertObject:imagename atIndex:toIndexPath.item];
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer,i think you don't understand my question~

Comment: @Baraiya Bhadresh : Add some explanation for your answer. Also, this does not answer the OP.